# SQL Plus Place column name on row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-concatenation

I am having some trouble with my code.

Current output:

```
COLUMN_NAME
-----------
Value 1
Value 2
```

Expected Output:

```
COLUMN_NAME: Value 1
COLUMN_NAME: Value 2
```

I am trying to do this with:

```
COLUMN STU_NUM  NEW_VALUE STU_NUMVAR NOPRINT
COLUMN LNAME  NEW_VALUE LNAMEVAR NOPRINT
COLUMN FNAME  NEW_VALUE FNAMEVAR NOPRINT
COLUMN RANK  NEW_VALUE RANKVAR NOPRINT
COLUMN STATUS NEW_VALUE STATUSVAR NOPRINT
TTITLE LEFT 'Student STU_NUM: ' STU_NUMVAR  -
LEFT 'Name: ' LNAMEVAR -
LEFT 'Rank: ' RANKVAR -
LEFT 'Status: ' STATUSVAR - 
SELECT STU_NUM, LNAME, FNAME, RANK, STATUS FROM STUDENT WHERE STU_NUM = '&StuID';
```

However currently I am not getting any output.

Answer (score 2):

To print column_name in all the rows, simply **CONCATENATE** the **column_name** as a **hard-coded string value** enclosed within **single-quotation marks**.

You could use the **concatenation operator** `||`.

For example,

`SELECT 'STU_NUM : ' || STU_NUM FROM STUDENT WHERE STU_NUM = '&StuID';`

Similarly, concatenate the column_name for other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

More universal decision will be to join your table with user_tab_columns, which can show you column names if your selected table. Try dsql to acomplish.